# deserialize json to object SerializationException

Tags: c#, json, xamarin

I try to deserialize a Json stream, but I get a SerializationException, I found this from the Microsoft [MSDN website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179(v=vs.110).aspx) does anybody see what we are doing wrong?

```
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer (typeof(Json));
Json flippo = (Json)serializer.ReadObject(dataStream);
(Json)serializer.ReadObject(dataStream);
```

system.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException has been thrown 
Expected element was 'root' but the actual input element was '' in namespace

Sample:

> {"d":"[{\"Student_ID\":1,\"Voornaam\":\"Thom\",\"Achternaam\":\"Jansen\",\"Email\":\"test@live.nl\",\"Created_Date\":\"\/Date(1410949696453)\/\",\"Lessen\":\"Engels\",\"Klassen\":\"H2A\",\"Paid_Version\":true,\"Geboortedatum\":\"\/Date(671752800000)\/\"}]"}
>   ]

Comment: show your sample json..

Comment: added a sample Json...

Comment: why does your json start with `]` ? what is it meant to represent? even if it was `[ {...`, that would denote an *array* of objects - for example, to be deserialized into a `List<SomeType>`...

Comment: Sorry, I copied it wrong. Fixed it

Comment: Your json is invalid. Remove last `]` and then try to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

Probablly your json is invalid, I'm not sure. But if you wnat a easy way, use the json.net library. Download and insall it via NuGet package manager. Is made by Newtonsoft. After installation it will appear on visual studio a quick demo. Very lightweight!

Hope it helps you!